# How to match number array with a string array

Tags: php

I have two arrays, $A is product_id array and $B is image filenames array.

Example:

```
$a = array("654345","665456","566676");

$b = array("filename_654345.jpg", "filename-file_566676.jpg");
```

How can i loop over every value from array $a and find that same value from array $b append to it.

Goal is to have a table like solution where product id and filename contains the same id.

Example:

1. 566676 - filename-file_566676.jpg
2. 654345 - filename_654345.jpg

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use foreach to loop through image names array and get the number with preg_replace() then loop through id’s array to check if number exists

```
$array_result=[];
foreach($names as $name){
    $x= preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $name);
    if(in_array($x,$ids)){
            array_push($array_result,[$x,$name]);
    }
}
```